# NSString to class instance variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsobject

I am looking for a way to convert from NSString to a class instance variable.  For sample code below, say filter is "colorFilter".  I want filternameclassinstancegohere to be replaced with colorFilter.

```
- (void)filterSelected:(NSString *)filter
{
    self.filternameclassinstancegohere = ….;
}
```

Comment: Does this class have a specific range of filters, and you are setting it by using a string? Have you looked at an enum instead?

Comment: Currently filter can be any of 40 NSString names.  The reason why I am looking to do this way so I do have to use the switch statement.

Comment: What is supposed to go after the =? i.e your ideal method is self.ColorFilter = _what_?

Comment: please see my answerer posted.

Comment: Oh! Now I see that, and re-look at your question, it all makes sense! Well done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there were good suggested solutions given for this question, I discovered what I needed is the NSClassFromString method.  Here is a final implementation:

```
- (void)filterSelected:(NSString *)filter
{
    //self.filternameclassinstancegohere = ….;
    self.myViewController = [[NSClassFromString(filter) alloc] initWithNibName:filter bundle:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using one NSMutableDictionary instance variable with string keys rather than 40 instance variables.

Comment: This is another good suggestion for another case.  But in my case, it can't be applied.

Comment: Key/Value coding like `[self setValue:@"SomeValue" forKey:filter]` might work. But this might cause security problems...

Answer (score 2):

You can create an arbitrary selector using `NSSelectorFromString()`:

```
SEL methodName = NSSelectorFromString(filter);
[self performSelector:methodName];
```

This will call a method `colorFilter` in your example above.

Would be wise to check with `respondsToSelector` before calling, too.

Comment: This is good suggestion for another case.  But in my case, I can't apply it.

Comment: If you could extend your question with exactly what it is you want to do, I'm sure we can get a solution for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If the filter value can only be a small, constant number of things, just use an enumeration and a switch statement:

```
enum Filter
{
  ColorFilter,
  FooFilter,
  BarFilter
};

- (void)filterSelected:(Filter)filter
{
  switch(filter)
  {
  case ColorFilter:
    self.colorFilter = ...;
    break;
  case FooFilter:
    self.fooFilter = ...;
    break;
  case BarFilter:
    self.barFilter = ...;
    break;
  }
}
```

If the set of filter values is large and could change frequently, then you could also use [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html).  It's more complicated but more flexible.

Comment: Good idea.  Unfortunately, as I just explained it to jrturton.  I don't want to use the switch statement.